# How I do to print through iPad using USB printer in iOS Swift application?

Tags: ios, swift

I need to print a receipt through the iPad using the USB Printer. Is it possible to connect and do a print using a USB printer through the iOS application?

Comment: Unless the printer has Mfi support you can't print to it.  If it does have MFi support then you will need to use the external connectivity framework. You will probably need to find a BLE or wifi receipt printer.

Answer (score 0):

Printing in iOS used to be done using UIPrintInteractionController, and, while that still works, it has a much better replacement in the form of UIActivityViewController. This new class is responsible for taking a wide variety of actions of which printing is just one, but users can also tweet, post to Facebook, send by email, and any other action that has been registered by another app.

If you have a UIImage you want to print, you can just pass it in. If you want to print text, you can wrap it inside an NSAttributedString with some formatting, then place that inside a UISimpleTextPrintFormatter object, then print that – iOS automatically takes care of pagination, margins and more.

```
func share(image: UIImage) {
    let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [image], applicationActivities: [])
    present(vc, animated: true)
}

func share(text: String) {
    let attrs = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 72), NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]
    let str = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: attrs)
    let print = UISimpleTextPrintFormatter(attributedText: str)

    let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [print], applicationActivities: nil)
    present(vc, animated: true)
}
```